# PHP stream post request not working, but works with curl

Tags: php, curl, stream

I want to send post request as php stream

```
$aruguments = http_build_query(
    array(
        'apikey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'appid' => 730,
        'min' => 20,
        'items_per_page' => 100
    )
);

$opts_stream = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/json' .
                     'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest',
        'content' => $aruguments
    )
);

$context_stream  = stream_context_create($opts_stream);
$json_stream = file_get_contents('https://api.example.de/Search', false, $context_stream);
$data_stream = json_decode($json_stream, TRUE);
```

For some reason i get error saying:

`failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`

If i send this same request with cUrl it works normaly but its very slow.

Here is my cUrl request that works

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.example.de/Search');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{  \"apikey\": \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"min\": 20,  \"appid\": 730,  \"items_per_page\": $number_of_items_per_request }");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Can you show us the cURL code as well? It helps us to have a reference of a request that works.

Comment: Also, you need to add line breaks for your headers. Each header needs to be on it's own line: `'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" . "foo: bar\r\n"`. Also notice the double quotes (or `\r\n` will be read as text instead of new line).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson If i send it like this i get error 400 Bad Request

Comment: _"If i send it like this"_ - Like what?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I also edited my question to show cUrl that works

Comment: @MagnusEriksson with headers that include line break and double quotes

Comment: Then I'm not sure you've implemented it correctly. However, you're also sending the data in the wrong format. Your cURL code are sending the post-data as json, while your first attempt (that isn't working) are posting the data as a x-www-form-urlencoded string. Try changing `$arguments = http_build_query(...)` to `$arguments = json_encode(...)` and test.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It works when i encode it and use line breaks and double quotes. Thanks !

Comment: I can write it up as an answer which you can accept so the question gets marked as solved

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the posted code.

#### Headers

When you're adding headers, you set them all in one single string. For the target server to know when one header ends and the other begins, you need to separate them using new lines (`\r\n`):

```
'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    . "x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest\r\n",
```

#### Post data

The big difference between your stream context and your cURL code is that your cURL code are posting the data in json-format, while you're stream context are posting the data as a x-www-form-urlencoded string. You're still telling the server that the content is json though, so I guess the server gets a bit confused.

Post the data as json instead by changing:

```
$aruguments = http_build_query(
    array(
        'apikey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'appid' => 730,
        'min' => 20,
        'items_per_page' => 100
    )
);
```

to

```
$aruguments = json_encode(
    array(
        'apikey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'appid' => 730,
        'min' => 20,
        'items_per_page' => 100
    )
);
```